# React - How to add multiple values for a the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add multiple values from an array to the state, but for some reasons, only the last one is added into the state

here is the code:

```
this.state = { languageList: {} };

const languages = ['English', 'Spanish', 'Russian']


languages.map(language =>
   this.setState({
     languageList: {
         ...this.state.languageList,
         [language]: true,
      },
   }),
);
```

Can anyone help?

Expected output:

```
languageList: { Engish: true, Spanish: true, Russian: true }
```

Comment: What is the expected value of state after the `.map`?

Comment: @CalvinNunes already updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `setState` only once rather than calling it into a loop.

If you do it into a loop, only the last `setState` will be applied because the previous ones haven't been executed yet.

```
this.setState({
  languageList: {
    ...this.state.languageList,
    ...Object.fromEntries(languages.map(language => [language, true]))
  }
}),
```

If you really want to call `setState` into a loop (I don't recommend it because it cause a lot of state updates), you must use the [updater function](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) to do the update from the previous state

```
languages.map(language =>
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    languageList: {
      ...prevState.languageList,
      [language]: true,
    },
  })),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're updating state based on previous values, you need to use the updater form:

```js
this.setState(prevState => ({
  languageList: {
    ...prevState.languageList,
    [language]: true,
  },
})),
```

This is because `setState` is async, and your loop will run to completion before the state is actually updated. Meaning `this.state.languageList` will be the same empty object for each iteration.